# Android google map - Get tiles that are in the camera

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on an android application with google map v2.

I'm currently trying to download tiles from internet that are in the camera. I have a custom `TileProvider` that takes in parameter X, Y and zoom. So, I would like to know what tiles are visible, so when I press the download button I can know witch tiles to download..

Do not confuse with putting in cache tiles that my provider download, I only want all currently visible tiles.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I don't have the code yet for this section. This is why I'm asking this question ;)